# Does rank() function partition by work with string type?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have used the `rank` function with `partition by` before and it works fine if we are partioning by a column of integer type. However, I tried with a column of string type and it didn't work. For the following query

```
SELECT Id, Email, rank() over (partition by Email order by Id) r
FROM Person
```

On table,

```
+----+------------------+
| Id | Email            |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | john@example.com |
| 2  | bob@example.com  |
| 3  | john@example.com |
+----+------------------+
```

I got the same output as the original table, which means `partition by` is making no difference. What is the solution for this?

Comment: Please provide sample data, current and desired results. You would need to explain what is wrong with the results you are getting, and which result do expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`partition by` works with strings.

In your example, it should return `1` on two rows and `2` on the second for "john".

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e1f8877b89354180bb4caf7d06eed1c6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Seems like some bug in leetcode, which is not showing me the rank column.

Comment: @MetallicPriest . . . If you are getting only two columns back from a query that has a `select` with three expressions, something else is the issue.

Comment: I just copied your query.